# Django application on Docker is starting up but browser gives empty response and localhost doesn't send any data

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have created a simple app with Django, Python3, and Docker on Windows:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt /code/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /code/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.2.22'

services:
  analyzer:
    build:
      context: ./analyser
    command: bash -c "python ./analyser/manage.py migrate && python ./analyser/manage.py runserver 8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: always
```

In my case, I don't need a DB. So I haven't added the details of it and 'depends_on'. I have read a few similar questions like this which says check the filename. My file names are 'Dockerfile' and 'docker-compose.yml'. I think I don't have any issues with filenames. I have tried like this 'python ./analyser/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000' But that also dosn't seem to works

Looks like the Docker is starting but from my browser, I get this response

```
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                                                                                 docker:default
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container version_1-analyser-1  Recreated                                                                                                                                                            0.1s 
Attaching to version_1-analyser-1
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 18, 2023 - 10:33:49
Django version 3.2.22, using settings 'analyser.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

But when I use the link in the browser it shows this:

```
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I am confused about what is that I am missing. I have little experience in docker for all those I followed the same procedure it worked. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the port 8000 on the Docker container is correctly mapped to the port 8000 on your local machine in the docker-compose.yml file. You have it set up correctly with "8000:8000"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` configuration looks correct to me.

There is onle one problem that I spotted is the Django application you are running inside the docker container starts up the web-server on local interface, i.e `127.0.0.1`. That's make it impossible to your browser to reach the server from your host machine.

The easy fix is to start the Django on `0.0.0.0:8000` address instead. Don't forget to restart the docker container by running `docker compose restart analyzer` after you make any changes.

It is possible that there is some other issues that need to be investivated. Don't hesitate to update your questions with information as it come.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried  to use "0.0.0.0:8000"  in the docker-compose file and ran it.  But now  it shows: `This site can’t be reached. The web page at http://0.0.0.0:8000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
`

Comment: Just to make sure ther is no misunderstanding. You should see the following line in your logs: `Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/`. And after the container is up and running, you should be able to access it via http://localhost:8000 from your host machine. One thing that might lead to confusion is that network inside container is isolated from network on your host machine and you need to specify port mapping.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ilya Khrustalev.  I was trying to access it via: http://0.0.0.0:8000/ this till now. Then I tried with localhost:8000. Now it is working perfectly.